# Redirecting a Wordpress blog using Django on Heroku

Tags: django, wordpress, heroku, reverse-proxy

I have a Django app running on Heroku, and I'd like to add a Wordpress blog to it. After some [background reading](http://rywalker.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-as-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app-also-hosted-on-heroku), it seems like the accepted solution for ***Rails*** is:

1. Deploy a separate Heroku Wordpress app solely for your blog
2. Use rack-reverse-proxy to redirect `mydomain.com/blog` to `myblog.herokuapp.com`

However I have not found an equivalent reverse proxy middleware solution for Django. Does one exist? If not, how would I go about rolling my own?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a reverse proxy just to do a redirect. Just use a view.

Create a view:

```
def blog(request, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    return redirect('http://myblog.herokuapp.com')
```

Attach view to a url in your urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog', blog, name='blog_redirect'),
)
```

Comment: I should have added that I'm not sure if a simple redirect will give SEO weight from the blog back to my original site. Which is why I thought a reverse proxy would be better.